# Automatic Send DTMF for Survey Campaign, Goautodial v3

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am using Goautodial V3 and i want to setup a campaign that sends automatic DTMF *2 as soon as the call has been answered, I have tried changing the agi-dtmf.agi file but it did not help, i also changed the outbound carrier dialplan but it still did not work. Can anyone help me out ? below is the carrier configuration that i used.

> exten => _4416658289.,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
>   exten => _4416658289.,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:10}@TFM,,tTo)
>   exten => _4416658289.,3,Wait(10)
>   exten => _4416658289.,4,AGI(agi-dtmf.agi,signalonly---*2) 
>   exten => _4416658289.,5,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=5)
>   exten => _4416658289.,6,Hangup

Comment: "Did not work" is not a really good explanation about what is wrong with your current solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use option D of **Dial** command.

```
D([called][:calling[:progress]]): Send the specified DTMF strings *after*
    the called party has answered, but before the call gets bridged.  The
    <called> DTMF string is sent to the called party, and the <calling> DTMF
    string is sent to the calling party.  Both arguments can be used alone.  If
    <progress> is specified, its DTMF is sent to the called party immediately
    after receiving a 'PROGRESS' message.
    See 'SendDTMF' for valid digits.
```

Comment: can you let me know the dialplan ? I have also tried using SendDTMF in the dial plan but it did not work.

Comment: Sorry, that will be out of scope for this site. You have do debug/experiment yourself. Will be greatly depend of your setup, so usless for other and require experiment on your setup.